# r: compile excel files by passing them as a list in dplyr

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, openxlsx

I have two excel files that I want to compile into a single dataframe in r.

First, create the excel files to reproduce:

```
df1<- cbind.data.frame(var1= rnorm(10,4,1), var2= rnorm(10,5,1), var3= rnorm(10,7,4)) # create df1
df2<- cbind.data.frame(var1= rnorm(10,4,1), var2= rnorm(10,5,1), var3= rnorm(10,7,4)) # create df2

wb1<- openxlsx::createWorkbook() # create empty workbook1
wb2<- openxlsx::createWorkbook() # create empty workbook2

openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb1, "df1") # add sheet 1 to wb1
openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb1, "df2") # add sheet 2 to wb1

openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb2, "df1") # add sheet 1 to wb2
openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb2, "df2") # add sheet 2 to wb2

openxlsx::writeData(wb1, "df1", df1) # write df1
openxlsx::writeData(wb1, "df2", df2) # write df2

openxlsx::writeData(wb2, "df1", df1) # write df1
openxlsx::writeData(wb2, "df2", df2) # write df2

openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb1, 'wb1.xlsx') # save wb1
openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb2, 'wb2.xlsx') # save wb2
```

My function below compiles a single, specified Excel file into a Dataframe, but I'd like to grab all files and compile them programmatically:

```
dfCompiled <- 'wb1.xlsx' %>% # rename DF and input your file name here
  getSheetNames() %>%
  set_names() %>%
  map(read.xlsx, xlsxFile = 'wb1.xlsx', # file name here
      colNames = TRUE) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

Call the dataframe to verify that it works:

```
> dfCompiled
    df1.var1 df1.var2    df1.var3 df2.var1 df2.var2   df2.var3
1  3.356598 4.441104  7.95931350 3.968744 3.349242  2.1997116
2  3.151004 4.822166  0.39571905 4.679021 6.230923 12.8589661
3  3.581085 6.367498 -0.06415929 5.810634 4.207270  9.9430692
...
```

What would be the best way to run the below list through these statements so tha all sheets are compiled into one dataframe?

```
filelist<- list("wb1.xlsx", "wb2.xlsx" )
```

Comment: `map_dfr(filelist, readxl::read_excel, .id = 'file')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_compile <- function(file){
  getSheetNames(file) %>%
  set_names() %>%
  map(read.xlsx, xlsxFile = file,
      colNames = TRUE) %>% 
  as.data.frame() 
}

filelist<- list("wb1.xlsx", "wb2.xlsx")

# Assuming same column names per xlsx file
map(filelist, df_compile) %>%
map_df(bind_rows)
```

Comment: this is excellent, i wanted to make one tweak and append the two dataframes rather than concatenate them, so that `dfCompiled` became wider instead of long. I replaced `bind_rows` with `bind_cols` but that didn't work, but `cbind.data.frame` does work. Any idea why? Either way, this works, thank you.